# Image data can't be converted to float

Tags: tesseract, opencv, python

```
#import required python modules
import cv2 # opencv
import pytesseract # tesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#read the text image using imread

org_img = cv2.imread("Poem.png")
plt.imshow(org_img) #display the read image
```

What is wrong with this code ??
I am getting the error that "**Image data can't be converted into float**"

Comment: Where does the error occur?  Can you upload your image to some free hosting service and post a link to your input image.

Comment: When I am plotting the image using plt.imshow() then it shows an error

Comment: Does it occur if you use cv2.imshow()? Can you post a link to Poem.png?

Comment: Here it is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_tcqBi3KAh6B_ntDcNq3i9spra6DZtX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not see anything odd with the file. Does it occur if you use cv2.imshow()?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to RGB first:

```
org_img = cv2.imread("Poem.png")
org_img = cv2.cvtColor(org_img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(org_img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python/OpenCV. You forgot to add `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow(org_img)`

```
#import required python modules
import cv2 # opencv
import pytesseract # tesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#read the text image using imread

org_img = cv2.imread("Poem.png")
plt.imshow(org_img) #display the read image
plt.show()
```